# Statfunc error when importing PyMC3 through Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, pymc3

The error that I am getting is:

**cannot import name 'statfunc' from 'pymc3.stats' (/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymc3/stats/__init__.py)**

I've installed using pip and conda, and am running Jupyter through Anaconda Navigator.

I am using Mojave 10.14, Python 3.7.

How do I fix this?